How to determine if client is inside or outside the office network using angluar
How to identify the user is accessing our our application from inside office or outside, based on that we have some functionality to build. hence what the recommendation to find the way to UI to identify the this application run inside office or not ?

Yesterday you were asking how to verify your device is connected to Ethernet. Now you're looking for the IP address, and this is similarly likely to be unusable. You can't get the IP address of the device directly from Angular, or any Javascript. You could get an address by querying some service like IPify but that is likely to give different addresses at different times depending on the location of the device, and probably none of them useful. Instead, explain what you're actually trying to do once you have this information. We might be able to help with that.

How to identify the user is accessing our our application from inside office or outside, based on that we have some functionality to build. hence what the recommendation to find the way to UI to identify the this application run inside office or not ?

Using angular alone running in the browser, you can't really get the system IP because the browser environment restricts direct access to system-level information.
But you could create a backend endpoint to call.
Or the easier way, is to use an API and retrieve the public ip:
https://api.ipify.org?format=json

Akos.one: thanks

Akos.one:   how the backend knows or detect the ip address ? backend also cant detect system ip address right ? only internet public ip ?

@Kirsh No sorry the system ip isnt detectable by the backend if the client is behind a router or firewall. The backend will only see the public ip address.

thanks any other recommendation ? how the system can identify the user logged in with inside office (inside company network) or outside of office networks / mobile/ tab ?

The only thing I can think of is: using the backend to check if the request comes from a specific ip-range. But ip spoofing and VPNs give me considerations..
